# Use computed data inside for each loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would live to make use of reactive data changes when using `v-model` for `<input>` tags.

Now I want to have a value inside a `v-for` loop to be updated automatically when `v-model` is triggered.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

```html
<tr v-for="(service, key) in services" :key="key">
  <td class="left aligned">
    <div class="title" contenteditable="true">{{ service.title }}</div>
    <div class="desc" contenteditable="true">{{ service.description }}</div>
  </td>
  <td class="price">
    <input v-model.number="service.price" type="number" min="0" /> &euro; / day
  </td>
  <td class="quantity">
    <input v-model.number="service.quantity" type="number" min="0" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="total">{{ service.total | currency }} &euro;</div>
    <div class="tva">+{{ service.total | tva(invoice.tax) }} &euro; ({{ invoice.tax }}%)</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Whenever I change the values inside the `inputs` `service.quantity` or `service.price`, they updates automatically, except those values in `service.total`.

Comment: Can you provide snippet of your `service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a method instead:

```js
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    getServiceTotal({ price, quantity }) {
      return quantity * price;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And in your template:

```html
<div class="total">{{ getServiceTotal(service) | currency }} &euro;</div>
```

Comment: Man, that's exactly what I've was trying to get. Works perfectly. Thank you !